# Broken link images in python google app engine

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

Hi I've tried many times to make an image link work using python/google app engine but it still shows a broken link.

i've the folder images in my root folder containing the images i want.

my app.yaml file:

```
handlers:

    - url: /.*
      script: helloworld.py

    - url: /images
      static_dir: images
```

my index.html:

```
img src="images/_image01.gif"
```

Answer (score 4):

Handlers are matching in order.  `/.*` will match any URL, so your /images handler will never be matched.  Reverse the order of them, and always put a `/.*` handler last in app.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the '/' at the beginning of the static path in your html file.  Try:

```
img src="/images/_image01.gif"
```